# Two Points Distance From My Path or KML /KMZ Calculating with Google Map javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I have a question about Google Map Javascript api. You know, google map calculating two points distance with city map. Can I use a kml, kmz way and calculate this two points distance from my kml/ kmz or points ?

Or how can I calculate ?

Comment: What does your KML/KMZ look like?  What two points do you want to calculate the distance between?

Answer (score 1):

If you know your coordinates, then you can use the geometry library.

1. You need to load the geometry library

   `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry`
2. The distance between two points is the length of the shortest path between them. This shortest path is called a geodesic. On a sphere all geodesics are segments of a great circle. To compute this distance, call `computeDistanceBetween()`, passing it two `LatLng` objects.

Example:

```
var a = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
var b = new google.maps.LatLng(0,1);
var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a,b);
```

`distance` will be the distance in **meters**.